# Iphone Background task even after application in closed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I keep reading the documentation and is just not making sense. So i decided to ask the question. Applications on the Iphone like the clock which has an alarm on it. When i set the alarm and close the application the application still notify's me at 4:30am eventhough i have closed the application. Now my understanding is that in order for something like this to work you would have to have it running on the background at all times. This is the part that does not make sense. If i completely shut down the app by double clickin my home button and then swiping up to get rid of the app, how does the app monitor time if is no longer running in the background?  Apple states that their are 5 states

**1-NOT RUNNING

2-Inactive

3-Active

4-Background

5-Suspended** 

explanation of the above are located [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)
i would imagine that when i shut down an application the state is not running. However the 
alarm application still comes on. HOW? this is killing me. Is there a special state that only native apps can have? 

Any information or further understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the alarm clock you are referring to is the one built into iOS on iPhone? If yes, this is an Apple product and for sure can do more than other apps can do. I don't know of other alarm clock apps that can do that.

Comment: Volker thats what i figuered but i wanted to make sure i was not loosing my marbles.Trying to further my understanding and i though perhaps there is something im missing.

Comment: Apple stated quick emphatically at WWDC this year that they interpret an App kill via the dbl-tap swipe up motion as user intent to stop that app from doing anything. The only way to resurrect the app is for the user to relaunch it.

Comment: you don't need the app to run, you can schedule a local notification and that notification will wake up your app. The local notification will be managed by iOS and not by a background run of your app. There is support for background mode but that one will not be continuous and your app should declare itself as one of (or combination of) location based, voip or audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the case Miguel. What you are looking for is:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Using UILocalNotifications, your app does not have to keep track of time at all. It schedules a notification, and the operating system keeps track of it. I have built quite a few apps with notifications/alarms. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you william. I read that over and over again and it wasnt until i read your post that it made sense. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Local notifications.

iOS will notify user when your previously added local notification fires. [iOS will add notification but your app **won't be running** at all. *When user will tap on the notification then the app will open.*]

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
   [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello world"];
   [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
   [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
   [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
}
```

> **Tutorial**:
> http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/
> http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/
>
> **Concept guide**:
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html